# Maven dependencies not published with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-publish

I have the following `build.gradle`:

```
group 'org.inthemoon.spring'
version '1.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.inthemoon.spring', name: 'childcontext', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}


tasks.create('sourceJar', Jar) {
    dependsOn tasks.classes
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier 'sources'
    extension 'jar'
    group 'build'
}


publishing {
    publications {
        nebula(MavenPublication) {
            artifact tasks.sourceJar
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run goal `publishToMavenLocal`, I get the following pom file `...\.m2\repository\org\inthemoon\spring\springfx\1.1-SNAPSHOT\springfx-1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.inthemoon.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfx</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

i.e. no dependencies.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your `pom.xml` has the content: `<packaging>pom</packaging>` indicates that no jar have been linked to the publication.

This is done by adding:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    nebula(MavenPublication) { // Note that 'nebula' here is the name of your publication
      from components.java
      // Other configuration instructions
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the plugins `maven` and `maven-publish` provide similar capabilities. `maven` is now considered deprecated in favour of `maven-publish`. And so in your build script you can remove the application of the `maven` plugin.